# Tell me as a response

Tags: politeness, answers

if someone  ask your opinion just with your name, is it rude to answer “tell me”?
For example, during a meeting, your boss exposes an idea and just say, Mely?is it rude just answering tell me

Answer (score 2):

As a native Engish speaker I don't recognise a bald "Tell Me" as a standard response and I'm not sure what your intention is.

> Boss: I think we should take option X, it seems to be most cost-effective. Mely?

I guess that's a request for you. Mely, to state your opinion. In my eyes this somewhat informal, but perhaps normal in your culture. I might expect:

> Boss: Mely what do you think?

Now I'm trying to understand what

> Mely: Tell Me.

means. In my environment I would see this as rather terse, and perhaps rude. I would always recommend in a formal situation using complete sentence as

> Mely: Please tell me what you need to know.

or

> Mely: I can follow that suggestion, please just tell me by when it needs to be completed.

Now already the boss has been quite terse, so if you already have an informal relationship, and that "Tell Me" is conventional in your environment then it may
be acceptable. In an unfamiliar environment I would err on the side of politeness.

Answer (score 2):

If your boss asks your opinion, you should tell your boss your opinion.

"Tell me" is an instruction.  It doesn't tell your boss your opinion.  So it doesn't respond to the boss in a meaningful way.  It would be rude.

You can't use "Tell me" like that.

> Boss: I think we should raise the price. Mely?
>
> Mely: I think that's a good idea./ I don't think that's a good idea because...